# Identical GET requests in CURL using PHP and Postman have different responses

Tags: php, api, curl, postman

I have to hit third-party API using curl in PHP but somehow I am getting a wrong response using curl but when I hit the same request using `Postman` I am getting the correct result.

**Multi curl**

```
$this->curlArray[$id] = curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->curlArray[$id], CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($this->curlArray[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($this->curlArray[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($this->curlArray[$id], CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
curl_setopt($this->curlArray[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($this->curlArray[$id], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_multi_add_handle($this->multi, $this->curlArray[$id]);
```

Above is multi curl using which we are hitting the request.

And using same request and same header we are hitting using postman we are getting a correct response.

If anyone face this issue let me know why I am getting this

Sample Request are below for compare:-

```
 Postman Request Parameters and header

    URL: XXXXXX.availability/vn52hfn4jwi5zhy?hotel_info=false&rates=false&hcode=H!0249886&bundled=true
    Headers:

    api-key:2f7ef83xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
    Content-Type:application/json
    Accept:application/json
    Accept-Encoding:application/gzip

    parameters:

    hotelinfo:false
    rates:false
    hcode:O987b


    CURL Request Paramters and Headers

    URL:XXXXXX.availability/vn52hfn4jwi5zhy
       parameters:{"hotelinfo":false,"rates":false,"hcode":"O987b"}

        Headers : Array
            (
                [0] => Content-Type:application/json
                [1] => Accept:application/json
                [2] => Accept-Encoding:application/gzip
                [3] => api-key:2f7ef83xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
            )

    )
```

Comment: Going the code and explanation you've posted: the requests are probably *not* the same.

Comment: I check request parameters and request header they are the same. Do i have to check anything else???

Comment: I don't know? There should only be one reason why the responses are different, and that is that the requests are different. Dump both raw requests, diff them and see if you can see differences. If they truly are the same, the API does something very weird and you should really contact its support.

Comment: Copy the Curl (PHP) code directly from postman, then run that in your PHP application to see if it works, then compare the curl settings to find out what the culprit was.

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments